Opt Out of Metrics Collection on Android WebView -- How to verify?
As per the android developer documentation @ https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/managing-webview#metrics,  WebView has the ability to upload anonymous diagnostic data to Google when the user gives their consent. Data is collected on a per-app basis for each app that instantiates a WebView. You can opt out of this feature by creating the following tag in the manifest's  element:
<manifest>
    <application>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut"
               android:value="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>

I don't understand on how can I really confirm this is working ?
When checking the network calls from web-inspector (on Chrome), I still see the same list of 3rd party calls (filter by google) independent of having this "...MetricsOptOut" change in manifest.
On https://www.securing.pl/en/webview-security-issues-in-android-applications/, I see the mentioning of calls to www.google-analytics.com domain. But when checked on the app with MetricsOptOut, still see the calls for this domain "www.google-analytics.com".
Could some please help me understand on how can be check and confirm the difference with and without this metrics-opt-out in android webview ?
Thanks.
I expect "www.google-analytics.com" network calls not to happen when the below is part of the manifest in the app.
<manifest>
    <application>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut"
               android:value="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>

